# bootstrap center progressbar on div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap progress bar as a loading indicator, and I want the progress bar to be a certain width with the whole thing centered in the DIV. But the progress bar doesn't seem to like being centered.

When I do:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/loading.gif" style="height:80px;" />
</div>
```

The image is centered properly. But when I substitute it for a progress bar, it goes to the left:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="progress" style="width:200px;"> <!-- set to certain width -->
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;">
            <span>
                Loading...
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/X6RpGdvJbA)

I want the progress bar to display centered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or, you can just use Bootstrap's `center-block` class

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="progress center-block" style="width:200px;"> <!-- set to certain width -->
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;">
      <span>
        Loading...
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/a0SXqv3g6N

Comment: ah, thanks. This is what I was hoping for, something that didn't require specific CSS. Bootstrap is spoiling me.

Answer (score 9):

This bit of css worked for me.

```
.progress { margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm the opposite of a CSS wizard, so I don't know basic things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to enhance the Marcelo answer, for those who are new to CSS (like me)

Remember to check the class in which your progress bar is located:

For me the progress bar was in "download > progress" class like:

```
<div id="download" class="download">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="main_slider" class="carousel slide banner-main" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <h3>Programming languages 1</h3>
                            <div class="progress" style="width: 50%">
```

So in my style.css I have added Marcelo answer, below the download css like this

```
.download {
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    background: #fff;
}

.download .progress { margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

and it worked, so do not be afraid of CSS, keep on taking Panga(challenges) with code ;)